# Excl & Incl. Tax Displaying same when customer is logged in

Tags: price, tax

I've noticed that my website is displaying both **Exclude Tax** and **Include Tax** same when log in. When I'm logged out, it is displaying calculations fine.

Any idea why it might be displaying like that?

Comment: Have u fixed this problem, because i found the same problem as this one. Do u have any advise ?

Comment: In order to answer I need more details like: are you using a custom made template or some extension for customer groups? are you talking about category and product pages or about shopping cart and checkout pages?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the customer is in a customer group which has incorrect tax calculations.

Every customer group is linked to a tax class this you can see in the Admin Panel under the Customer > Customer Group (M2.2.2) or System > Other Settings > Customer Groups (M2.1). In this overview you should see differences in the tax classes.

When there is differences in the tax classes it is possible that the tax rules for the calculation are different.

Another explanation is that when you login the country of the logged in user’s address is combined to a different tax rule then the Default Country which is used for not logged in users.